# How to include non browsable field in xmlserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

When i am serializing List of custom object. Non browsable fields are omitted in result.

it is example of propertry in C# 4.5

```
[DisplayName("G.Amt"), Browsable(false)]
public decimal GAmt { get{ return qty * rate; } } }
```

I want to include this property in xml output. Please suggest which attribute will work to do this.

Edit

I realize that browsable(false) is not cause to omit this property in xml output. Actually readonly properties omits in xml serialization.

[Force XML serialization to serialize readonly property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585364/force-xml-serialization-to-serialize-readonly-property)
this question describes the actual problem and its solution. It seems that this question is duplicate. But in above described question provided solution is just a trick. Here i am asking for any attribute that can resolve this problem.

However in the above question @Marc Gravell answered to use [DataMember] attribute.
But when i am using this, an error generated

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize type 'BusinessObject.SaleProductDetailBusinessObject' because it contains property 'GAmt' which has no public setter.
```

Please provide any attribute to resolve this issue.

Comment: What XML serialization utility are you using?

Comment: i am working in C# 4.5. using System.Xml.XmlWriter