# What's wrong with Property without set?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, properties, datacontract

I have a class used with a WCF service.

Interface defined

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetMyStuff/?p={param}",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
MyResponseObject MyMethod(string param);
```

Among it's properties I had

```
public bool IsDecorated {
  get {
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Decoration);
  }
}
```

resulting request refused to load.

After I added a

```
set { }
```

it worked.

Any piece of a clue?

Comment: Readonly properties are not serialized. Because when they be deserialized back they will not have setter. Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401192/why-are-properties-without-a-setter-not-serialized

Comment: `set{}` does not make it unreadonly

Comment: Compiler is not concerned whether you have written a logic inside it. All it cares is that your property should have a setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readonly properties are not serialized. Because when they will be deserialized they will not have setter. To avoid that issue, read-only properties are not serialized in the first place.

Same case when `set` is `private` like

```
public List<Foo> Bar {get; private set;}`.
```

Read
[Why are properties without a setter not serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401192/why-are-properties-without-a-setter-not-serialized)
[Force XML serialization to serialize readonly property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585364/force-xml-serialization-to-serialize-readonly-property)
[Why isn't my public property serialized by the XmlSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575432/why-isnt-my-public-property-serialized-by-the-xmlserializer)

Compiler is not concerned whether you have written a logic inside setter. All it cares is that your property should have a setter.